# -Call static method from loaded swf or -How to expose an API for client movies

Tags: actionscript-3

I have main movie A that loads (with a Loader) another movie B inside. In movie A I have a class API, with a bunch of static methods that perform actions in A.

```
A.as
public class Main extends MovieClip{
 public Main()
 {
   b= new Loader();
   b.load("b.swf");
   addChild(b);
 }
}
-------
API.as
public class API{
   public static function DO_STUFF() { ... }
}
-------
B.fla
API.DO_STUFF();
```

The fact is that I cannot do this last call, because API class is not available at compile time (but it is on run time).. Could I delay this check to run time? How could I expose API to loaded movies (done by clients)?

I found I can make a interface/bridge function in A, like this:

```
public function DO_STUFF() { API.DO_STUFF(); }
```

and then call this from B:

```
MovieClip(parent.parent).DO_STUFF();
```

but it seems to be very ugly and unadequated to me.. I'd rather prefer an **API.do_stuff()** type of call.

any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this class reference in a most proper way by typing it, like the following:

```
var API:Class;
```

And in the complete handler you can safely get it:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

private function eventCompleteHandler(event:Event):void{
    event.target.content.API = getDefinitionByName("API") as Class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple solution:

Clients must declare API var simply with:

```
var API;
```

so I can link this variable with my API class after swf loading is complete:

```
private function eventCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
   event.target.content.API= API;
}
```

and then clients can call to any API function with **API.func();**

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by throwing events. It's not a good idea to call functions directly. Instead, you can listen to an event in the loaded class and dispatch it in the loader.

### A.as

```
public class Main extends MovieClip{
 public Main()
 {
   b= new Loader();
   b.load("b.swf");
   addChild(b);
 }
}
```

### API.as

```
public class API{
   public function API():void {
      this.addEventListener('DO_STUFF',DO_STUFF);
   }
   public static function DO_STUFF() { ... }
}
```

### B.fla

```
// instead of API.DO_STUFF();
MovieClip(parent.parent).dispatchEvent(new Event('DO_STUFF'));
```

Dispatching an event is always free of errors. Either there's someone to listen to it, or it dispatches into nothingness.

Comment: Very interesting. I don't like the syntax in B.fla (ugly for the client to write down), but I like the event approaching. Let's see if I can beautify it.

Comment: I'm not very sure where you include the API class.. You could add the event listener in A.as: b.content.addEventListener('DO_STUFF',DO_STUFF); And then the code from the B.fla would be this.dispatchEvent(...) or simply dispatchEvent(...)

Answer (score 0):

### A.as

```
package
{

    import flash.display.Sprite

    import flash.display.Loader

    import flash.events.Event

    import flash.net.URLRequest

    public class A extends Sprite
    {
        private var api:API;

        public function A():void
        {
            api = new API();

            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.sharedEvents.addEventListener("DoStuff", DoStuff);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, AddSWF);
            //normally put error listener in here
            loader.load(new URLRequest("B.SWF"));       
        }

        private function AddSWF(e:Event):void
        {
            // No Need to Load to Stage if no Visible Conent - just vars etc
            //this.addChild(e.target.content);
        }

        private function DoStuff(e:Event):void
        {
            trace("Calling DoStuff in API Class");
            api.DoAPIStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

### API.as (included in A.swf)

```
package
{   

    public class API
    {

        public function API():void
        {
            trace("API Ready");
        }

        public function DoAPIStuff():void
        {
            trace("API is DoingStuff()");
        }
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

### B.as (Doc Class of B.swf)

```
{

    import flash.display.Sprite

    import flash.events.Event

    public class B extends Sprite
    {
        public function B():void
        {
            trace("B Loaded");
            loaderInfo.sharedEvents.dispatchEvent(new Event("DoStuff", true));
        }
    }
}
```